# Upgrading to Material Design Lite 2.0

Tags: angular2-mdl

Are there any plans to move the MDL version to 2.x or 1.3 works perfectly fine? I can see that some of the components that exists in the mdl-ext already exists in the 2.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes there are plans to move to https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web.

Long answer: The intention of angular2-mdl was to provide components that are stable and can be used today without a lot of breaking changes. You may know there are material component libs for angular2 but most of them are still in beta state. Material Design Lite (getmdl.io) was a perfect match because it was already stable for a long time.
The followup version of mdl has moved to https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web. So in fact there will be no mdl version 2.x. The current version of material-components-web is 0.3.0 - e.g. not a stable version with a lot of work todo. If there is a release candidate version it is planned to provide an angular version that makes the integration as easy as possible - like the current version of angular2-mdl is for mdl version 1.3.